# Meaning of $(\nabla_x + \nabla_\xi)^n$

Tags: notation, partial-derivative, tensors

what does $(\nabla_x + \nabla_\xi)^n$ mean? (In the context, $x,\xi\in \mathbb{R}^d$). In my notes, the author states this should be a tensor, but what exactly does he mean. Is this clear notation?

My operator acts on a function $f:\,\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$.

So in one dimensions, this is $(\partial_x + \partial_\xi)^n f$.

Note, the dimension is $d$ and in general $d\neq n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is meant that $n$ is dimension of the tensor. This means that $$\left((\nabla _x )^n\right)_{i_1,\dots i_n}  =\partial_{x_{i_1}}\dots \partial_{x_{i_n}}$$  where $i_j \in \{1,\dots d\}$ for $j\in\{1,\dots, n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it means an operator defines using covariant derivatives, which we can write recursively, as in: $$(\nabla_x + \nabla_\xi)^nV = (\nabla_x+\nabla_\xi)(\nabla_x+\nabla_\xi)^{n-1}V$$ for $n > 1$, and $$(\nabla_x+\nabla_\xi)V = \nabla_x V + \nabla_\xi V,$$ where $\nabla_x V = (x[v_1], \ldots, x[v_d])$ and $\nabla_\xi V = (\xi [v_1], \ldots, \xi[v_d])$, where $V = (v_1,\ldots, v_d)$ is a vector field in $\Bbb R^d$. If we had more context, maybe I could speculate something better..

---

I also saw the notation $\nabla_\xi f$ to designate the directional derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}$, but I am not sure if this is standard. The above remarks would still apply in this case, with this interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I put in more details.

Comment: I fixed a few things in an edit.

Comment: In our course $\nabla_{x}$ normally means $(\partial_{x_1},\dots \partial_{x_d})$. That's why I am confused.

Comment: I think you meant $\nabla = (\partial_{x_1},\ldots,\partial_{x_d})$, so that $\nabla f = (\partial_{x_1}f,\ldots,\partial_{x_d}f)$?

Comment: I meant, $\nabla_x = (\partial_{x_1},\dots , \partial_{x_d})$.

Comment: Oh, and shouldn't it be $f: \Bbb R^d \times \Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R$?

Comment: It is neither of them. Definitely $f$ is not a vectorfield and $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^d$ so I don't see what you mean by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}$.

Comment: These covariant and contravariant things, where to read about them?